# How to pass JSON data from express to a javascript/jQuery script in pug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, pug

I am trying to pass some JSON data from an express route to a .js file which is in a .pug template. I can't figure out how to achieve this. I am trying as follows:

The router:

```
// Office Locations
router.get('/office_locations', (req, res, next) => {
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM office_locations ORDER BY oloffice';
  var params = [];
  pool.query(sql, params, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.render('office_locations', {title: title, tabledata: JSON.stringify(result.rows)});
    }
  });
});
```

The PUG file:

```
extends layout

block content
  .container
    include menu.pug
    .workspace
      .map-content
        .map#map


  include main-addons.pug

  link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="")
  script(src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin="")
  script(src="/javascripts/office_locations.js")
  script(src="/javascripts-dev/table.js")
```

The file where I require the tabledata information is table.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get the table data
  var tabledata = !{tabledata};
  console.log(tabledata);
});
```

But am getting always false when logging to console.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code before the `script(src="/javascripts-dev/table.js")` line:

```
 script(type='text/javascript').
   window.tabledata = "#{tabledata}";
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out that I needed to use a window variable.